# How to backup ms access database in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

How to backup ms access database in vb.net?
We're gonna make a system for a certain company but our teacher doesn't teach us at all, please help. Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to make a backup of an Access-Database (or any one-file-databases) is to simply copy the file. But watch out for Exception because the file might be locked.

```
System.IO.File.Copy( _
    "C:\Your\original\database.mdb", _
    String.Format("D:\BackUps\{0:yyyyMMdd}.mdb", Date.Today) _
)
```

Additionally you could allow the user to specify the location and filename to which the file should be copied to. That's a rather trivial approach with simply utilizing the `System.Windows.Forms` controls [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) and [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx).

```
Using openDialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    openDialog.CheckFileExists = True
    openDialog.CheckPathExists = True
    openDialog.Filter = "Microsoft Access Database (*.mdb)|*.mdb"
    openDialog.RestoreDirectory = True

    Using saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        saveDialog.CheckFileExists = False
        saveDialog.CheckPathExists = True
        saveDialog.FileName = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".mdb"
        saveDialog.Filter = "Microsoft Access Database (*.mdb)|*.mdb"
        saveDialog.RestoreDirectory = True

        If openDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK AndAlso saveDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            If File.Exists(openDialog.FileName) Then
                File.Copy(openDialog.FileName, saveDialog.FileName)
            End If
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

In case you wonder what those [`RestoreDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory.aspx) property is doing: Those two dialogs are moving the current directory of the application to the designated paths, which might yield interesting effects later on if you assume a still unchanged current directory. To prevent this behavior, we set this property.

Comment: That's it. An Access database is just a Windows file, to do a backup just copy the file (either to a CD, DVD, external drive, or on a backup server).

Comment: A file-system copy of a Jet/ACE data file may or may not be valid. It depends on whether or not users have it open and in a state that won't be properly copyable. The only reliable way to back it up is via the Jet/ACE database engine, which will never create an inconsistent copy.

Comment: @David: The question was, how to back it up...well, that's one way of doing it (at least in my eyes). He never specified any conditions to match.

Comment: thanks! maybe I could slightly change the code that you gave so that I could make it work with an open file dialog box?

Comment: I would assume that if you want to backup a file, you want that backup to be usable. Doing it with a file system copy may work 99% of the time, but it's that other 1% that's going to be an issue.

Comment: @David: What if the 99% is the case here? I still think we're talking about generic solutions, and not solutions to a problem he did not mention. Though, if you know an answer for the 1% then please feel free to post it, I'm sure somebody will find it helpful.

Comment: Absolutely agree with David on both accounts. Another "workaround" is to check if the .LDB file associated with the MDB exists, although this is not always a true indication of the database's state as a crashed MDB will sometimes leave an LDB on the file system.

Comment: @Bobby - Guaranteed that 1% situation *will* occur, especially when it comes to Access (that's hard experience talking). And just because it wasn't mentioned doesn't mean it's not part of the problem - or should not be considered. The 1% is what often evolves into bugs. It's our responsibility as developers to consider and solve for them in the solution. It's also important - in fact, I'd say our 'responsibility' - to pass this knowledge on to new developers.

Comment: @Jason: In that case I'll have to pass...I had the luck to never _really_ work with Access. But if you have another solution, please post it.

Comment: @Bobby asks: "if you you know an answer for the 1% then please feel free to post it." I refer you to my first comment, which concludes: "The only reliable way to back it up is via the Jet/ACE database engine, which will never create an inconsistent copy." From where I sit, it seems to me that I've already done what you asked for.

Comment: @David: I thought along the lines of an example...I mean, I, f.e., have no idea how to do that without breaking my fingers. And, I would be interested to hear how to do that (I'm always open to learn new things, even if I'll never need them).

Comment: How to backup via Jet depends on your programming environment. In Access, you'd use DoCmd.TransferDatabase for the data tables. For a full backup with all properties (including, e.g., RI) it gets more complicated, and you might instead use a shell template database and append the data. The former will be faster, but the latter will get you a copy that could be dropped into replace a corrupted main file. Outside of Access, you'd have to do either of these things through DAO or ADO or OLEDB. I could provide code for DAO, but not for the others, as I'm an Access developer and don't use them.

Comment: And, BTW, if you're using a Jet data store from VB.NET and don't actually know how to use Jet, maybe you should choose a different data store.

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer this: [how to make backup and restore in vb](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/740363/how-to-make-backup-and-restore-in-vb#answer2)[^]

I'd suggest to use the MS Access **compact database** method. See: [How to compact a Microsoft Access database by using Visual Basic .NETenter link description here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306287)

Comment: See also [How to compact a Microsoft Access database by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306287) on MSDN.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, i referenced it in my answer ;)

Comment: You did not include any link. I edited your answer to include the link.

Comment: Follow the first link. There you'll find a reference to MS article ;) BTW: thank you, Olivier ;)

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
If File.Exists(openDialog.FileName) Then
                File.Copy(openDialog.FileName, saveDialog.FileName)
            End If I GOT ERROR ON THIS
```